# Google Analytics. Enhanced Ecommerce. Limit for product impressions

Tags: google-analytics

Does anyone know something about limits for sending impressions data for enhanced ecommerce (Google Analytics)? I found strange behavior, that sending data more than about 8KB is restricted by google. I use data layer for sending ecommerce data. I have up to 100 products on page, also I use unicode to send product and category names. So, I have much data to send. And the worst, that GA don't track pageview. It just do not send collect request at all, if I try to push to much data. In documentation I didn't anything about it. Any ideas how to avoid such limit?

Answer (score 3):

As for the first part of the question, the limit for a http request to the Google Analytics endpoint is 8192 bytes - this is stated in the documentation for the measurement protocol (which is the basis for Universal Analytics).

My only idea to avoid such a limit would be to send only a product id and custom attributes to make the http request smaller and try to use dimension widening to add product names etc. in the Analytics interface. However I have not tested this and am not quite sure if dimension widening can be applied to product data (**UPDATE** to add: At least with Enhanced Ecommerce enabled one can indeed upload product data   and custom attributes for given SKUs/product names).

Comment: we limited impressions data only to id and brand, but using full list of features is impossible now. maybe, it's a problem of non-English language + url encoding = more than 8k.

Comment: also, we decide to try using events and send data about impressions by portions by 10 products

Answer (score 0):

I am encountering this same problem. My solution thus far has been to page results.

As stated above, limiting the attributes being sent could help reduce the size.

Google's sample:

```
ga('ec:addImpression', {            // Provide product details in an impressionFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel/T-Shirts',   // Product category (string).
  'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
  'variant': 'Black',               // Product variant (string).
  'list': 'Search Results',         // Product list (string).
  'position': 1,                    // Product position (number).
  'dimension1': 'Member'            // Custom dimension (string).
});
```

This could potentially be reduced to:

```
ga('ec:addImpression', {            // Provide product details in an impressionFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel/T-Shirts',   // Product category (string).
});
```

Thoughts, ideas?

Comment: we limited impressions data only to id and brand, but using full list of features is impossible now. maybe, it's a problem of non-English language + url encoding = more than 8k. we decide to try using events and send data about impressions by portions by 10 products

Comment: Hello @alex13 may i ask how you exaclyt implemented it? as I am having the same problem. thanks

Comment: hi @rjtubera. sorry for delayed response. actually the trick was to send impressions by portions using not pageview, but event. so, we created dummy event like "send_impressions" and do 4-5 such events with portion of impressions. so, finally, initially, we added 1 pageview and 4-5 events to data layer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
if you only can send 10 products for impressions, **add this code every 10 products:**

**ga('send','event','Ecommerce','Impressions','NamePage',{nonInteraction: true});**

Example:

```
ga('ec:addImpression', {            // Provide product details in an impressionFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel/T-Shirts',   // Product category (string).
  'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
  'variant': 'Black',               // Product variant (string).
  'list': 'Search Results',         // Product list (string).
  'position': 1,                    // Product position (number).
  'dimension1': 'Member'            // Custom dimension (string).
});
....
....
ga('send','event','Ecommerce','Impressions','NamePage',{nonInteraction: true});
a('ec:addImpression', {            // Provide product details in an impressionFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel/T-Shirts',   // Product category (string).
  'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
  'variant': 'Black',               // Product variant (string).
  'list': 'Search Results',         // Product list (string).
  'position': 1,                    // Product position (number).
  'dimension1': 'Member'            // Custom dimension (string).
});
...
...
```