# Google Analytics error in ga("send", "pageview") on certain pages

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

After implementing Enhanced Ecommerce, I'm finding that a very small subset of pages are showing up in Google Analytics as *not* having the Analytics code.

On inspection of the source, there is no difference between the code on those pages that are failing and those on the pages that are validating correctly.

I installed the GA Debug Google Chrome extension and I can see that on a few pages there is an error coming back from the `ga("send", "pageview")` call.

However, I can find no information in any documentation or anywhere online that describes possible errors from the `ga("send", "pageview")` call or gives any information that may help to diagnose any possible issues.

Importantly there are no javascript errors on the page, the only way I can see anything at all is with the GA Debug plugin - which some people state doesn't really work very well! Nevertheless Google is showing an unknown problem with this small subset of pages.

Here's a sample of the code on one of the pages:

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1 *new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-500228-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'ec');   // Load the advanced ecommerce plug-in.
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');   // Load display advertising.
ga('set', '&cu', 'GBP'); // Set currency

// Add generated analytics elements from the request container
ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021109021CB'
    ,   'name':         'Cam shaft, Type 4 Mechanical Std. (No Cam Wheel)'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     1
    ,   'price':          148.75
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '071109021CB'
    ,   'name':         'Cam shaft Type4 Hydraulic Std  (No Cam Wheel)'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     2
    ,   'price':          133.92
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021198541'
    ,   'name':         ' Cam bearing set, std, 1.7-2.0 [43]'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     3
    ,   'price':            9.93
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021109309G'
    ,   'name':         'Cam follower 1.7-2.0 Type4 engine 72-78'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     4
    ,   'price':            9.00
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '022109309'
    ,   'name':         'Cam Follower Hydraulic Type 4/WBX & CT Engine'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     5
    ,   'price':           14.17
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           'AC10920091'
    ,   'name':         ' Lifters, Type 4 Scat Lube-a-Lobe Set of 8'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'SCAT'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     6
    ,   'price':           95.33
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021109301A'
    ,   'name':         'Pushrod, Type4 with Solid tappets, 271mm'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'VW'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     7
    ,   'price':           24.83
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021198335'
    ,   'name':         'Pushrod Tube and Seal Kit for Type 4 Engines 1700-2000'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'KITS'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     8
    ,   'price':           40.33
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021109335C'
    ,   'name':         'Push rod tube 1.7-2.0 Aircooled'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'SSP'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     9
    ,   'price':            4.92
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021109335CSS'
    ,   'name':         'Push rod tube 1.7-2.0 Aircooled Stainless Steel'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'KAEFER'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     10
    ,   'price':            8.58
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021109345A'
    ,   'name':         ' Pushrod Seal, Between Tube & Case,1.7-2.0, Small [37]'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     11
    ,   'price':            0.42
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021109349B'
    ,   'name':         ' Pushrod Seal, Tube to Head, 1.7-2.0, Large 25.1  [37]'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     12
    ,   'price':            0.42
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021109339'
    ,   'name':         'Retaining wire, push rods tube 1.7-2.0'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     13
    ,   'price':            6.42
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '113109651A'
    ,   'name':         'Valve collet, all aircooled, WBX, Diesel and Golf 1100-1800'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     14
    ,   'price':            0.83
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021109641B'
    ,   'name':         ' Retainer, valve spring, 1.7-2.0 [38]'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     15
    ,   'price':            3.72
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021109623K'
    ,   'name':         'Valve Spring, Type4 1.7-2.0'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     16
    ,   'price':            4.17
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021109601'
    ,   'name':         'Inlet valve, 1.7 & 1.8 8/74-&#62; (39.3mm x 8mm Stem)'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'IVAM'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     17
    ,   'price':            5.42
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '022109601'
    ,   'name':         ' Inlet valve, 1.8, 8/73-7/74 (41x8mm) [39]'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'IVAM'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     18
    ,   'price':            8.74
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021109601A'
    ,   'name':         'Inlet valve, 2.0, 8/75-79 (37.5mm)'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'IVAM'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     19
    ,   'price':            5.83
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '022109612D'
    ,   'name':         'Exhaust valve, 1.7-2.0, 33mm'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'IVAM'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     20
    ,   'price':            8.25
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '022109612A'
    ,   'name':         ' Exhaust valve, 1800cc, 34mm* [50]'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'IVAM'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     21
    ,   'price':            8.50
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021101403A'
    ,   'name':         'Valve Guide, Inlet, Type 4 Engine'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'IVAM'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     22
    ,   'price':            3.36
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '021101417A'
    ,   'name':         'Valve guide, exhaust, 9mm'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'IVAM'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     23
    ,   'price':            3.33
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '022109443'
    ,   'name':         'Rocker arm, Inlet, 2.0 Aircooled 76-83, 10mm screw'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'VW'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     24
    ,   'price':           21.00
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '022109463'
    ,   'name':         '**NLA** Rocker arm, Exhaust, 2.0 Aircooled 76-83, 10mm scr'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     25
    ,   'price':           21.00
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           'N0110077'
    ,   'name':         'M7 nut for 1.7-2.0 Type4 rocker shafts'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     26
    ,   'price':            0.25
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '043109451'
    ,   'name':         'Valve screw, Best Quality ,1.2-1.6, 8/60-, 8mm'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     27
    ,   'price':            1.67
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '022109451'
    ,   'name':         'Adjusting screw,valve,1.8-2.0 2.1DJ,1.9DG 89-, 10mm,NOT 1.7!'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     28
    ,   'price':            3.33
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           'N0111525'
    ,   'name':         ' Nut, 8mm valve adjuster+general use [10]'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        ''
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     29
    ,   'price':            0.34
}); ga('ec:addImpression', {
        'id':           '028109453'
    ,   'name':         'Nut for 10mm valve adjusting screw'
    ,   'category':     'Bay Bus 1968-79/Bay Bus 1968-79 Type 4 Engine Parts - 1.7, 1.8 & 2.0 litre/Valvetrain, Pushrods & Camshaft'
    ,   'brand':        'VW'
    ,   'list':         'Product listings'
    ,   'position':     30
    ,   'price':            2.08
}); 

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This is identical to many other pages that *are* working correctly, with different product data obviously - so I'm wondering if the product data itself is causing an issue.

The error I can see in GA Debug is as follows:

```
Error: type={0: "len", 1: 9199} method= message= account=  
M.log
O
fc
pc
(anonymous function)
gc.(anonymous function).H
ad.(anonymous function).send
b.(anonymous function)
jf.R
jf.H
Z
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
```

The last three anonymous functions are from ec.js and the rest from analytics_debug.js.

Of course, all of this could be a red herring as it's coming from the debug and not GA itself - but I have no other indicators of a problem outside of Google denying that these page have code on them!

Comment: Code example is too dense, not useful. Please share a link to a page where your error is reproduced

Comment: Really? Whenever I condense the code down in one of these questions, somebody shouts at me that I can't expect anyone to debug without the *exact* code I'm using!!
If you paste it into an editor that highlights javascript, you should find it very readable as it goes... nevertheless the page it's from is here:  https://www.vwheritage.com/shop/bay-bus/type-4-engine-parts-17-18-20-litre/valvetrain-pushrods-camshaft/

Comment: The page you linked to looks like its working fine. No errors.

Comment: I agree - no errors... except that Google Analytics explicitly states that this page has no Analytics code - and when I look at the Google Analytics Debugger, I get the error detailed above (in the debugger, not the console). Have you looked at the page with the Google Analytics Debugger enabled?

Comment: Seriously? The effort that went into this question and it gets downvoted? WTF? I need some help here and with Google ridiculously silent, I have nowhere to turn. Thanks SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got same error message too.

> Error: type={0: "len", 1: 18608} method= message= account=

I searched how to solve this problem on the Stackoverflow. And I found an article. You may have interest in it.

The article says:

> the limit for a http request to the Google Analytics endpoint is 8192 bytes - this is stated in the documentation for the measurement protocol (which is the basis for Universal Analytics)

To avoid such a limit you may limited impression data to make the http request smaller. After I read this article I limited impression data only to id and brand, price. I excluded name data.

You may refer this Stackoverflow article by Eike Pierstorff.
[Google Analytics. Enhanced Ecommerce. Limit for product impressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628669/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-limit-for-product-impressions)

Comment: What about that link was helpful? Generally here, just posting links is frowned upon because the website behind the link might change or disappear. It's best to take the important parts of the website and bring them here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't know the risk that the link might change. To respect the original author I choose to write only about the link. Following your advice, I modified a little.

Comment: The link was to another article on Stack Overflow - if that goes down, this page will have gone down too! As the OP, I found this answer and the link very helpful. So, that's a downvote for the original question and a derisive comment on the only helpful response received. My but SO is becoming a very unpleasant part of the web, no?

Comment: I will try out the suggestion and accept the answer once confirmed. Thanks for the help.