# GA Enhanced Ecommerce: "No Http Response Detected" on list pages

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm trying to correctly configuring *Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce*  and I'm using [Tag Assistant (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk) for checking errors and warnings.

On my ecommerce, when I navigate to pages with list of products, showing more than 12 products in a single page, I get this error from Tag Assistant:

> No HTTP Response detected

[image]

After a lot of testing I noticed that:

- Showing less products in a single page (let's say 8 products instead of 12) the error disappears.
- Leaving 12 products per page but removing some data sent with the `ec:addImpression` command (for example removing `category` and `brand`) the error disappears but it appears again showing 24 products (or more) per page.

This is the code executed on a page when I get the above error, with a `ec:addImpression` command for each product inside the page:

```
ga("create", "UA-NNNNNNN-1", "auto")
ga("require", "ec")
ga("set", "&cu", "EUR")

ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "488", name: "Light Coral", list: "Cateogry Page", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "4.50", brand: "Coral", position: 1})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "487", name: "Light Purple", list: "Cateogry Page", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "4.50", brand: "Purple", position: 2})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "489", name: "Light Pink", list: "Cateogry Page", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "4.50", brand: "Pink", position: 3})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "491", name: "Light Red", list: "Cateogry Page", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "4.50", brand: "Red", position: 4})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "717", name: "Light Blue", list: "Cateogry Page", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "6.00", brand: "Blue", position: 5})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "768", name: "Light Pink 2", list: "Cateogry Page", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "8.00", brand: "Pink", position: 6})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "92", name: "Light Green", list: "Cateogry Page", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "5.95", brand: "Green", position: 7})
// ...

ga("send", "pageview")
```

Did someone experienced the same problem?

What may be the cause of the error?

Comment: Can you install GA Debugger (Chrome) and reload your page? You should be able to see if there are any other errors. It could be that the payload size of the hit exceeds 8192 bytes. I've seen this before when impressions includes too much information.

Comment: @nyuen Yes, I'm using both _Tag Assistant_ and _GA Debugger_.The code executed on the page, that you can see in my question, is from the GA Debugger (removing the prefix `Running command: `). But I don't see any error in the console. Is it possible that for only 12 products the hit exceeds the limit of 8k?

Comment: @nyuen If it is due to the payload size, do you know if is there a way to send the impression of 12 or more products when the page load without exceed the limit?

Comment: Well, if it was a payload error, you'd see the error message in the console. But you're saying it isn't the case. If it were, you could throttle the number of impressions sent. For example send 5 impressions at a time. You would need to loop through the impressions and just send a few, and then move onto the next set of impressions, etc. Alternatively, you could send "true" impressions, ie. only when the item is visible above the fold, then do you send the impression. Items below the fold are not actually visibly until you scroll down.

Comment: you may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265032/google-tag-manager-error-no-http-response-detected

Comment: [little bit more explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628669/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-limit-for-product-impressions) on this topic